# JQuery cannot be used in Watir with PhantomJS after adding the script into the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, watir

I'm trying to interact with website with no JQuery by using **Watir** and **PhantomJS**.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :args => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']
browser.goto 'http://putlocker.is/'

browser.execute_script(    
  "var the_script = document.createElement('script');
  the_script.setAttribute('src','http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js');
  document.body.appendChild(the_script);"
)

browser.execute_script('$("div").hide();')
```

With **Firefox** instead of **PhantomJS** it works fine - JQuery is loaded on a page and I can manage elements using JQuery. But **PhantomJS** raises this error:

> **{"errorMessage":"Can't find variable: $","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"41","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:8910","User-Agent":"Ruby"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"$(\\"div\\").hide();\",\"args\":[]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/84f7d6d0-7035-11e4-a8b8-85c94f571d8e/execute"}}
>   (ReqHand)**

I guess this issue is somehow related to this question: [Can't find variable - PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302928/cant-find-variable-phantomjs). But how to change **Watir** code so that it works?

Comment: Thanks, again and again I forget that javascript needs this strange time policy with Watir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS seems to behave differently from Firefox. It may be the case that PhantomJS is simply faster, it may also be that PhantomJS doesn't wait for the script to download. In either case you need to wait for the script to load. You can of course wait a static amount of time, but it is always better to wait just the right amount of time.

```
browser.execute_script(injectScript)
Watir::Wait.until { browser.execute_script("return !!window.jQuery") }
browser.execute_script('$("div").hide();')
```

Comment: I think Firefox also doesn't wait for script to download.

Comment: `!!$` doesn't seem to work (it always returns true), but looks like `!!window.jQuery` works fine.

Comment: That is strange. I'm going to change it. Thanks!