# Setup selenium with headless chrome error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to get selenium running with a headless chrome in the following environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6
- Chrome: 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- ChromeDriver: 77.0.3865.40
- Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358

I've been reading about it at [developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and followed the recommended [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome](https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/) post. I followed the steps in the ipython REPL:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.binary_location = '/usr/local/bin'

options.add_argument('headless')

options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

But this results in the following error:

```py
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-658404e774ae> in <module>()
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I've been looking around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657649/8374833) answer. I've seen there the `'headless'` argument is passed like this: `add_argument("--headless")`. I've tried to add it with the `'--'` but with the same exception as result.
In [this comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4961#issuecomment-365251536) the `--no-sandbox` argument is recommended as well but adding this argument doesn't change anything in my case neither.

**How can I debug and fix this error?**

Update based on the answer from Wonka:

I've changed `options.add_argument('headless')` to `options.add_argument('--headless')` and `options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')` to `options.add_argument('--window-size=1200x600')` with the same error as above.

Then as recommended I tried to set resolution after `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)` but this line already fails.

Comment: You might want to switch to FireFox driver. I had also problems with headless Chrome.which disappeared once I switched to FireFox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple changes, full path

```
#Pass binary on init object
##options.binary_location = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

options.add_argument('--headless')
```

## Extra options on my code

```
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
```

## Edit2:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
```

To set resolution I use this, after init driver object

```
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
```

Comment: Seems to work. I am not getting any error on init anymore. Passing the executable path directly did it.