# Is there a way to hide the browser while running selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a project with selenium to scrape the data, but I don't want the browser to open and pop up. I just wanted to hide the browser and also not to display it in the taskbar also...

Some also suggested to use phantomJS but I didn't get them. What to do now ...

Comment: with selenium, you can set option of browser to headless

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using Chrome you can just set the headless argument like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver_exe = 'chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_exe, options=options)
```

Answer (score 4):

To hide the browser while executing tests using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [python](/questions/tagged/python) you  can use the [minimize_window()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.minimize_window) method which eventually minimizes/pushes the *Chrome Browsing Context* effectively to the background using the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
driver.minimize_window()
```

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can use the **`headless`** attribute to configure [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) to initiate [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browser in *Headless* mode using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)

Comment: Well it doesn't hide the window... It just minimizes it.

Comment: @AndrewWhiteman Still that should serve your purpose of _...hide the browser..._, however I have updated the answer, let me know the status.

Comment: @Abhaysalvi: "It just minimizes it". Yes, and it's exactly what I was looking for. This way, the browser window doesn't disturb me when it opens, but I can still access it when I want to.

Answer (score 2):

For chrome you could pass in the --headless parameter.

Alternatively you could let selenium work on a virtual display like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

display = Xvfb()
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')

print(driver.title)
driver.quit()

display.stop()
```

The latter has worked for me quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox, try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

driver_exe = 'path/to/firefoxdriver'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(driver_exe, options=options)
```

similar to what @Meshi answered in case of Chrome

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide chrome or selenium  driver there is a library pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

window = [ x for x in pyautogui.getAllWindows()]
```

by this, you are getting all window  title
now  you need to find your window

```
for i in window:
    if 'Google Chrome' in i.title:
        i.hide()
```

or you can play with your driver title  also