# Python Selenium: How to make browser window not open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

how to make selenium window not open? i don't want see open window, but i need use selenium, because i need get info about headers, who load very slow.
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH =".\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1")


allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
for header in allheader:
     print("Header: " + header.text)
```

i was try use `phantonJS()` but hten my code not working and getting

```
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
```

i was trying use `xvfbwrapper` too, but getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skriptas.py", line 8, in <module>
    from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
  File "C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xvfbwrapper.py", line 15, in <module>
    import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

Any idea how to do it? Thank you for help.

Comment: Would you consider about using another web browser?What you need is the headless mode, but edge don't support this.

Comment: what browser support headless mode?

Comment: Firefox or chrome.

Comment: if my server have no graphical interface like FreeBSD  ? what i need to do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message...

```
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
```

...wasn't an error as such but the deprecation warning of [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) support.

---

### Solution

Use the following line of code to supress the error:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: but not workink my code than Traceback (most recent call last):
```File "skriptas.py", line 17, in <module>
    allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))      
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:```

Comment: @Kalakutas Your question heading was _...How to make browser window not open..._ and a concern with the `deprecation warning`. Hence was my answer. Of coarse the answer doesn't address the finding of elements. You may need to raise a new question for your new requirement.

Comment: ohh, but your code just ignore first warning about Selenium support for ```PhantomJS has been deprecated``` its not solve my problem here.

Comment: @Kalakutas True, please reread your question heading _...How to make browser window not open..._ which points to the warning but not the element finding part.

Comment: fine, you win :/

Comment: @Kalakutas The real winner is you, an integral part of this StackOverflow user community.