# Scraping with Python bs4 text extract out of HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the value from  `<div class="number">` as seen in the below image, but the output returns `None`,
how do I go about getting that value?

The HTML:

[image: HTML i am trying to extract is attached here]

The code I have already tried:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from pylogix import PLC   

my_url = 'https://www.aeso.ca/'
uClient =  uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
report = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"number"})

print(report)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, so `requests` doesn't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.aeso.ca/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(URL)
# Wait for the page to fully render before parsing it
sleep(5)

# The source of the page is in the `page_source` method of the `driver`
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
driver.quit()

report = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "number"})
print(report)
```

Output:

```
[<div class="number">10421 <span class="unit">MW</span></div>, <div class="number">$37.57 <span class="unit">/ MWh</span></div>]
```

To only get the text, call the `.text` method:

```
for tag in report:
print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
10421 MW
$37.57 / MWh
```

To only get the output for "Pool price", use a CSS Selector:

```
print(soup.select_one(".chart-price div.number").text)

# Or uncomment this to only extract the price, and remove `/ MWh` from the output
# print(soup.select_one(".chart-price div.number").text.split("/")[0])
```

Output (Currently):

```
$37.57 / MWh
```

Comment: Works great thank you very much. is there anyway not to show the web page when the script runs?

Comment: @Boonz You can run the browser in headless mode. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver) post.