# Python WebScraper with BS4 and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a webscraper with BS4 that will grab a specific date . I was able to build the webscraper but it is pulling the wrong dates.

The trouble I am running into is that they share the same class, I tried by id but i get a return results of []. How else can I specify this date and not others?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://nemsis.org/state-data-managers/state-map-v3/colorado'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

date = soup.find('span',class_='state-updated-on')
date = date.text

print(date)
```

and it returns `February 16, 2017` but I am looking for `09/04/2019`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use class and id?

Comment: <span id="commitDate-refs/heads/release-3.4.0-3" class="state-updated-on">9/4/2019</span>

Comment: can't you use `find_all` to get all values - and later use `index` - ie. `all_values[1]` - to get only one value which you need?

Answer (score 2):

The page is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. We can [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://nemsis.org/state-data-managers/state-map-v3/colorado"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait for the page to fully render
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("span", id="commitDate-refs/heads/release-3.4.0-3").text)

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
9/4/2019
```

Comment: To run Selenium in headless mode see: [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver).

Comment: @S.Caruso Glad to help! Consider marking this answer as accepted.