# Web Scraping html using python

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract 2 sets of data from:
"https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing"
using a python script and drop it into a list or dictionary. I've tried Selenium and BeautifulSoup as well as request.
All of them return an empty: [] or None. I've been at this all day with no success. I have tried to use the full xpath as well to try to index the location of the text, which had the same result. Any help at this point would be much appreciated.

```
##########################################################
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, features="lxml")
listing = soup.find(class_='mainTitle___mbpq1')
print(listing) 
###########################################################
import requests
from lxml import html

def main():
url = "https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
text_val = tree.xpath('//div[@class="item___2ffLg"]')
print(text_val)
###########################################################
```

[1st text between '(' ')', 2nd text is Date/Time after 'Trade: '](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Lmc.png)

(The only way i was even able to get the page in a text format that actually contains the part of the page i'm looking for, is by saving it as an *.mhtml format manually.)

Comment: There is a typo in the xpath - `//dev[@class="item___2ffLg"]`. The tag name should be `div`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo while writing this up, corrected it. Re-ran it still getting " [ ] " as an output.

Comment: @SankoHunbucse This can be done very easily with selenium and python. Let me know if you ok with that solution. I can share that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained, the data is loaded by an API. You can use the same to extract the details using `requests`.

Have only tried for `page 1`.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.kucoin.com/_api/cms/articles?page=1&pageSize=10&category=listing&lang=en_US")

jsoncode = response.json()

options = jsoncode['items']

for i in range(len(options)):
    title = options[i]['title']
    date = options[i]['summary']
    print(f"{title} : {date}")
```

```
Cryowar (CWAR) Gets Listed on KuCoin! World Premiere! : Trading: 14:00 on November 12, 2021 (UTC)
Deeper Network (DPR) Gets Listed on KuCoin! : Trading: 06:00 on November 12, 2021 (UTC)
Vectorspace AI  (VXV) Gets Listed on KuCoin! : Trading: 8:00 on November 12, 2021 (UTC)
...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for this. It seems to work very well, I will now just work on parsing the letters between the "(" &")"   and the date after "Trading: ".

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chrome Developer Mode and Refresh your site and now go to Network Tab Left side you will get search option just paste first Crypto War.... line in that

Now you will get URL which is used to reflect data in webpage you can click on headers to get URL and copy that and call it using `requests` module which returns `json` response

```
res=requests.get("https://www.kucoin.com/_api/cms/articles?page=1&pageSize=10&category=listing&lang=en_US")
res.json()
```

Output:

```
{'success': True,
 'code': 200,
 'msg': 'success',
 'timestamp': 1636695390265,
 'totalNum': 461,
 'items': [{'id': 10358,
   'title': 'Cryowar (CWAR) Gets Listed on KuCoin! World Premiere!',
   'summary': 'Trading: 14:00 on November 12, 2021 (UTC)',

    ...
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your comment, I have tried it out and it does return the text I need, I think this solution, with the one below in a loop might work, i will give that a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the response from the request.get method and saw that the initial source code is plain javascript. You have to wait for its execution to finish to parse the final rendered html. If you are fine with using selenium as you have tried with that, here is a solution I came up with to get the first element. Adjust the timeout based on your internet connection speed

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing")
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "info___1vA3W"))
    )
    title = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    date_desc = elem.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
    title_text = title.text
    date_text = date_desc.text
    print(title_text, date_text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Generic approach: Wait for all elements to be visible and cycle through them to print the elements. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657649/4741470) for running headless chrome so it doesn't open browser window. Added regex search for convenience

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
driver.get("https://www.kucoin.com/news/categories/listing")
try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'info___')]"))
    )
    for el in elements:
        title = el.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        date_desc = el.find_element_by_tag_name("p")
        title_text = re.search(r'(?<=\()[A-Z]+', title.text, re.I)[0]
        date_text = re.search(r'(?<=Trading: ).+', date_desc.text)[0]
        print(f'Title: {title_text}; Date: {date_text}')
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I have just tested it ( I just changed the webdriver to Chrome). When i run this from pycharm it opens chrome browser. Is there a way to have it not open and run in the background? (as this would be a function which would need to be seamless). Also where would the loop be to cycle through all of the classes with the same name to essentially gather all of the new listings and dates?  Thanks Again.

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your requirements. But if scraping itself isn't necessary and you just want to get the data, you can make the api call which the web page itself makes as the other answers have suggested