# Selenium Scrapy in headless mode still opening Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, headless

**QUESTION**

1. I'm trying to run a Selenium Scrapy scraper in headless mode (code below)
2. Scraper worked properly in 'headful' mode, ie with opening the Chrome browser
3. When I add the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver?rq=1) and run again, the scraper runs as if nothing changed. I.e., it runs like before, and opens Chrome
4. Working on Windows machine. Chrome browser version 111

What should I change to make it run in headless mode? All suggestion are much appreciated. Thank you!!

**CODE**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
import gspread
import scrapy 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--headless")

gc = gspread.service_account(filename = 'credentials2.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('api_key').sheet1

class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'techleapsesc'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://finder.techleap.nl/investors.accelerators'
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, wait_time= 3)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("Line 24 - inside parse function")
        quote_item = QuoteItem()
        
        print("Line 27 - before for loop")
        print(response.css('div'))
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            quote_item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').get()
            quote_item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').get()
            quote_item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').getall()
            self.sh.append_row(list(quote.values()))
            print(quote)
            yield quote_item
```

Tried different ways of invoking headless mode

Answer (score 0):

Change the below (Java code):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--headless")
```

To (Python code):

```
options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
```