# Can't play YouTube video on VPS when disconnect selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, youtube, bots, vps

I have a code play YouTube video
it works normally in my computer and VPS when I connect
but when I disconnect video is not played
I dont have any idea for this problem

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
service = Service(executable_path=web_driver_path)
driver = Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('')
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Play']").click()
```

Comment: the website i go to have a iframe in this have a video and need to click on it to play video

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657649) might solve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver)