# Where to publish data scrape script using python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I created a script using python that will scrape the data from a particular site. Is uses selenium and requires chromium browser. The script is working perfect and my problem is I want to deploy it a cloud server. What cheapest hosting service where i can deploy my app? is it needed to be VPS?

Thanks in advance.

This is my first time to publish this kind of app.

Ant

It is currently deployed on my old laptop and running 24 hours.

Comment: Try https://www.pythonanywhere.com/, they have a free tier, depending on the size of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy this on a VPS using a [headless chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver) browser. You can keep it running using some kind of a process monitor like npm2 or supervisord. Digital ocean has cheap VPSs you can use. The other option is to use a cloud based scraping provider and deploy there. e.g. Zyte.